# Why is $ 2\binom nm^2<n^{2m}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

$\forall n\geq2 \forall m\geq2,$ $$ 2\binom nm^2<n^{2m}.$$

Why is the above inequality, which is equivalent to $ \binom nm<\frac{n^m}{\sqrt 2}$, true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\binom nm =\frac {n (n-1) ... (n-m+1)}{m!} < \frac{n^m}{m!}$$
Thus, if $m \geq 2$
$$\binom nm^2 < \frac{n^{2m}}{m!^2} < \frac{n^{2m}}{2}$$
But your bound is very crude!